# Objective-C: Zooming Different UIScrollView Separately

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am making an app that uses a camera/photo library to put images on a `UImageView` that is inside a `UIScrollView`.

I am making something a frame app that will post images on different boxes. For example, in one view a user can put 3 images on a certain area, and once it is posted they can zoom/edit the image. I used `UIScrollView` in order to zoom the image, but i can't manage to zoom each image.

I have no issue when i only have one image on it, i have manage to zoom it properly.

This is the only code that i know for the zooming:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return insertPhoto1;
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Anyone here??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:  (float)scale
{

   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;

}
```